# max Y Axis value in a Highchart

Tags: highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/BYeBa/

```
yAxis: {

           min: 0,

           max: 75,

           title: {

               text: ''

           }
```

I am not sure why I cannot set the max value of the y axis in this highchart.  I don't want it to go over 75.  None of the data I have populate even goes near the value of 75.

Why does it stay at 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by endOnTick. If you set

```
endOnTick:false
```

75 will be your max.

See http://jsfiddle.net/kzoon/BYeBa/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can set tickInterval as 25.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval